# Is it possible to use local account password for shared folders access with Microsoft account?

Tags: user-accounts, windows-11, login, shared-folders, microsoft

Now I use Microsoft account for Windows 11 and login with PIN. But for shared folders in my local network I need to enter the long and hard Microsoft account password. Earlier I use my local account short digits password, but now It's impossible.
What can I do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Change to a local account and use your own, short, password: https://pureinfotech.com/switch-from-microsoft-account-to-local-account-windows-11/

Comment: You can use either a Microsoft Account or a Local Account, but not both at the same time. Make a batch file for shared folders - that is what I do and I use a Microsoft Account.

Comment: @John what's batch file?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I can't switch to local account because widgets doesn't work with it.

Comment: I provided an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to combine a Microsoft Account with a Local Account for purposes of sharing files.

You can use a batch file (list of commands) to connect to shared folders.

To connect to a folder (or drive) in a local network, use a batch file as described below.

Make a text file (Notepad works) with the following entries

NET USE Z: \*computernmame**Drive_or_folder*  /user:*microsoftaccount* password
.

NET USE Y: \*computernmame**Drive_or_folder*  /user:*microsoftaccount* password

In Notepad, File Save As and pull down the account type to All Files and save as  (say) connect.bat

This will save a batch file on your desktop and you can double click it to connect to your shared folders.

This works and I use it myself.